# Edit the value of every Nth item in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

What's the most pythonic way of performing an arithmetic operation on every nth value in a list? For example, if I start with list1:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I would like to add 1 to every second item, which would give:

```
list2 = [1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
```

I've tried:

```
list1[::2]+1
```

and also:

```
for x in list1:
    x=2        
    list2 = list1[::x] + 1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `slicing` with a list comprehension as follows:

```
In [26]: list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [27]: list1[1::2] = [x+1 for x in list1[1::2]]

In [28]: list1
Out[28]: [1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
```

Comment: I noticed many people put their answers in this format. How do you generate this?

Comment: Using the console in Enthought Canopy. Do you use a console?

Comment: I write code in Notepad ++ and will just use the python command line interpreter when I need to try something out. I don't have admin rights on the machine I write most of my code on. What is a difference between a console and the interacrtive interpreter (``>>>``)

Comment: With something like Canopy you have access to the variables created when running your program

Comment: This looks like it's just the iPython interpreter, rather than being specific to one IDE.

Comment: @Igor, try IPython; that's where the `In/Out` format comes from.

Answer (score 9):

[`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) allows you to use `+=` operation with slices too:

```
In [15]: import numpy as np

In [16]: l = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

In [17]: l[1::2] += 1

In [18]: l
Out[18]: array([ 1,  3,  3,  5,  5,  7,  7,  9,  9, 11])
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [v+1 if i%2!=0 else v for i,v in enumerate(list1)]
[1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(1, len(list1), 2):
    list1[i] +=1
print(list1)
```

using i%2 seems not very efficient

Comment: That `%` is not efficient might have been right 20 years ago. On any modern CPU it is as fast as any other basic mathematical operation.

Comment: `%2` is extremely efficient on integral types.  For divisors which aren't powers of two, not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for i in range(1,len(list1),2):
    list1[i] += 1
```

Comment: I'll stick my neck out and say that I prefer this answer to slicing. Why? Because it's an instance of a general form which is extremely Pythonic and extremely powerful: `for i in generator(args):`

Comment: Seems like an exact duplicate of Divisadero's answer posted 10 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator representing the delta (`itertools.cycle([0, 1])` and then add its elements to your existing list.

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> [a + b for a,b in zip(list1, itertools.cycle([0,1]))]
[1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [i for i in range(1,11)] 
#a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = [a[i]+1 if i%2==1 else a[i] for i in range(len(a))] 
#b = [1, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 9, 9, 11]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11679194)