# How do I mutate every third element in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, mutation

How do I check every third element in a list?

ie. Given the list below, I want to mutate every third item and leave the rest of the list as is.

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Basically, if the third element in the list (in this case `3,6,9`) is odd, then subtract one to make it even. If it is even, let it remain the same.

I know that if I do `L[2::3]` I get a new list of every third element, but I simply want to loop through every third item and check.

What would the for loop look like? I need some help.

Thanks and appreciate all help!

Comment: You may know this but just to be safe: make a copy of the list first and iterate over that, and mutate the other list. As Raymond Hettinger once said, "If you mutate something while you're iterating over it, you're living in a state of sin, and you deserve whatever happens to you."

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/36011478/1324033

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Don't overthink this.* This is a case where list comprehensions, functions, and so on are all overkill. You need to iterate over a list, and modify it in-place, right? So you're not modifying the structure you're iterating over. The iteration target is actually the *indices* of the list.

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(xs)

for idx in range(2, len(xs), 3):
    if xs[idx] % 2 == 1:
        xs[idx] -= 1

print(xs)
```

This is the equivalent of a `for(i = 2; i < len(xs); i++)` loop in many lower-level languages.

---

Compared to the list comprehension solution  proposed in another answer, the `for` loop is marginally faster:

```py
from timeit import timeit


def in_place(xs):
    for idx in range(2, len(xs), 3):
        if xs[idx] % 2 == 1:
            xs[idx] -= 1
    return xs


def list_comp(xs):
    xs[2::3] = [i - 1 if (i % 3 == 0 and i % 2 != 0) else i for i in xs[2::3]]
    return xs


# This answer is an improvement, as it eliminates one modulus
def list_comp2(xs):
    xs[2::3] = [x - 1 if x % 2 else x for x in xs[2::3]]
    return xs


context = {"globals": globals(), "setup": "xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]"}
print(f"For loop: {timeit('in_place(xs)', **context)}")
print(f"List comprehension:  {timeit('list_comp(xs)', **context)}")
print(f"List comprehension 2:  {timeit('list_comp2(xs)', **context)}")
```

On my machine, this produces:

```
For loop: 0.608657514
List comprehension:  0.7510721879999999
List comprehension 2:  0.641639047
```

Comment: You can just use: `if xs[idx] % 2:` and I don't agree to *"...and so on are all overkill"*.

Comment: Although this answer might produce the correct output, it will be significantly slower than a method with list comprehension and even less clear. Thus, I think you should consider accepting either @Austin’s or my answer as they are basically one liners and much faster overall.

Comment: My instinct was that list comprehensions would be slower in this case, so I wrote a benchmark. I have added it to the post. I'll also stand by my opinion that a for loop, which is a nearly universal construct, is easy to read compared to Python's extremely unusual list-slice assignment, which I have never used in real code in many years of writing Python. Golfing? Yes. Real code? Nah.

Comment: (Adding another list comprehension from @Austin's answer as well; it performs better due to using only one modulus operator.)

Comment: Your analysis is statistically insignificant as you only tested 1 instance. Run it for 1000 trials and then we can compare. Also your time testing script doesn't actually run for some reason.

For 1000 trials, I get: 
`For loop: 0.00033839699995041883
List comprehension:  0.00024323000002368644
List comprehension 2:  0.00026264899997840985`

As you can see, the for loop method you provided is slower than both list comprehensions (which is expected behavior).

Comment: `timeit`, which is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), runs its snippets many times. In this case, one million (the default). In any case, you're right, the difference isn't particularly significant; the difference in _readability_ is more important.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a list comprehension using slicing to modify selected values based on condition:

```
L[2::3] = [x - 1 if x % 2 else x for x in L[2::3]]
```

**Example**:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

L[2::3] = [x - 1 if x % 2 else x for x in L[2::3]]
# [1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
```

Comment: This seems to over-complicate the problem so that the conditionals are simpler. See my answer to see what I mean.

Comment: @lbragile, See my comment on your answer.

Comment: just wondering why are you assigning specifically back to the sliced list? Can’t this be any variable?

Comment: OP wants to retain all other elements in the list as it is. We take the slice, modify and place it back to the slice, thereby all other elements remain untouched.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function you want to apply to the elements an iterate using a list comprehension

```
def do(number):
    if number%2 == 1:
        return number -1
    else:
        return number

[do(y) if i%3 == 0 else y for i,y in enumerate(L)]
```

a different solution not using `enumerate` explicitly could be:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
    if i%3 == 0:
        L[i] = do(L[i])
```

You also might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804790/in-place-modification-of-python-lists/51804807) about inlace operations

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to do the loop without using enumerate?

Comment: You need the iteration count in order to keep track of the increments.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you using `i//3` (true division) instead of `i%3` (module - remainder)?

Comment: because I just woke up :). Changed it. Thanks

Comment: but that was a requirement? `Basically, if the third element in the list (in this case 3,6,9) is odd, then subtract one to make it even. If it is even, let it remain the same.`

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension is the best option:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L[2::3] = [i-1 if (i%3==0 and i%2!= 0) else i for i in L[2::3]
print(L)
```

## Output:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8]
```

## Explanation:

Basically you look at each *third* element in L and see if it is divisible by 3 (remainder is 0) AND not even (mod2 is not 0) and if so subtract 1 from it, otherwise keep it as is. Replace result in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to slices and in this example then use a list comprehension to do the mutation.

```py
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
L[2::3] = [ x if x % 2 == 0 else x-1 for x in L[2::3] ]
print(L)
```

Though despite the syntactic beauty, a simple for loop reads better for your future self and colleagues =D

Comment: A tiny simplification: `L[2::3] = [x-x%2 for x in L[2::3]]`